# Mongoose, populating field returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know my `notifications` field of my `user` has objects in it but when I call populate on `notifications` they are disappearing.

#### Populate Code

```
User.findById(socket.request.user._id).populate('notifications').exec(function(err, user) {
        console.log('get notification populated user', user);
        var unread = user.unread;
        var notifications = user.notifications;
        socket.emit('take notifications', {
            notifications: notifications,
            num_unread: unread
        });
    });
```

#### User Schema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
    },
    organization: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill in an organization name'
    },
    position: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill in the title of your position'
    },
    displayName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your email'],
        match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: 'testing error message',
        required: 'Please fill in a username',
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyPassword, 'Password should be longer']
    },
    salt: {
        type: String
    },
    provider: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Provider is required'
    },
    providerData: {},
    additionalProvidersData: {},
    roles: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: ['user', 'admin']
        }],
        default: ['user']
    },
    updated: {
        type: Date
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    /* For reset password */
    resetPasswordToken: {
        type: String
    },
    resetPasswordExpires: {
        type: Date
    },
    notifications: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Notification'
    }],
    unread: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was saving the `Notifcations` when I was creating them. So I changed this

```
    notification = new Notification(notification);

    console.log('pushing notification', notification);
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: data.to }, {
            $push: { notifications: notification },
            $inc: { unread: 1 }
        },
        function(err, model) {
            if (err) console.log('Error updating user with new notification', err);
            else {
                // console.log('sending notification to', toSocket.id.substring(toSocket.id.indexOf('#') + 1));
                toSocket.emit('new notification', { notification: data.notification_type });
            }
        });
```

to this

```
 notification = new Notification(notification);
    notification.save(function(err) {
        console.log('something went wrong saving the notification');
    });
    console.log('pushing notification', notification);
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: data.to }, {
            $push: { notifications: notification },
            $inc: { unread: 1 }
        },
        function(err, model) {
            if (err) console.log('Error updating user with new notification', err);
            else {
                // console.log('sending notification to', toSocket.id.substring(toSocket.id.indexOf('#') + 1));
                toSocket.emit('new notification', { notification: data.notification_type });
            }
        });
```